# How to take off .html from example.com/page.html

Tags: domains, url, url-rewriting, cpanel

I am using cPanel to build a website and I am not sure how to take the `.html` or `.php` file extension off my webpages.  Usually I will use a python framework and I do the routing manually but I am not sure how to do it with cPanel.  I saw something about using `.htaccess` but I am not sure what I would need to put in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you'd remove the .html extension using a `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# Replace html with your file extension, eg: php, htm, asp
```

To add a trailing slash at the end of the URL
(for example: `http://www.example.com/about-us/` to go to `http://www.example.com/about-us.html`)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html 

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @anaglo does this have any effect on seo ?

Comment: @sam yes if your website has already been indexed with file extensions changing your URL structure will most likely affect your rankings. You'll have to create 301 redirects from the old pages to the new pages. If it's a new website it does not matter which you use

Comment: great thanks!  any idea how to set my default page?  I have the line DirectoryIndex index.html site-down.php in there and my page is called index.html but it is showing a different one.

Comment: What page is it showing?